# How can I know the name of country?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know how can get the name of the country for who installs my app like whatsapp or line app.

**Hints:**

**1** - in the settings I choose U.S.

**2** - in app store I choose Saudi Arabia store.

I am currently in Jordan, when installing and open the (whatsapp or line) application is automatically choosing Jordan directly, and it does not ask me to allow location services to calculate?

So it is not reading it from setting or from store setting or from location services...

So how can I know user country???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CTCarrier class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596), which gives you the MCC.

Comment: thank you man really you help me...

this site have code to get MCC  (mobile-country-code)
http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/carrier-information-mobile-network-code-mnc-and-mobile-country-code-mcc.html

and this xls give you all data for countries and network from MCC
http://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thesmsworld.com%2FCoverage-Price-SMS.xls&ei=wI5kT5uyEMnS0QWdgc2wCA&usg=AFQjCNHAYvgtpRPJohPSfIpPzl5YM2qpjg&sig2=oxltLJp9VqqzZX6YY02SpA

this for anyone have same issue